# mongoexport too many options error while creating changelog

Tags: mongodb, changelog, mongoimport, mongoexport

trying to use mongoexport to export a csv of the oplog... tried all quote combinations I have read so far...

```
../mongodb/bin/mongoexport --csv -d local -c oplog.rs -o export.csv -f {op,ns,o._id} -q "{ts: { \"$gte\": Timestamp(1355100998000,1)} , op :{ \"$nin\" : [\"c\",\"n\"]}"
```

but I keep getting

```
ERROR: too many positional options
.....
```

what could be wrong?

After a lot of screwing around I have tried this

```
q="{op: { \$nin: [\"c\",\"n\"]}}"
mongoexport --csv -d local -c oplog.rs -o export.csv -f {op,ns,o._id} -q "$q"
```

and this works like a charm.
but still this

```
q="{ts: { \$gte: Timestamp(1355100998000,1)}, op: { \$nin: [\"c\",\"n\"]}}"
../mongodb/bin/mongoexport --csv --db local --collection oplog.rs -o changelog.csv --fields op,ns -q "$q"
```

does not work. Output

```
 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: ts: { $gte
```

Feel something is wrong with Timestamp()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally this is how it should be done... or how I did it. It is pretty fast tried it on 30000 records takes max 2 seconds.
All thats happening is that I am storing the results in a new collection by using mongo with           --eval option

```
q="db.oplog.rs.find({ ts : { \$gte : Timestamp( $timestamp, 1)}, op : { \$nin : [\"c\",\"n\"] } }, { op : 1 , ns : 1 , \"o._id\" : 1 , h : 1 } ).forEach(function(x){db.changelog.save(x);})"

../mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017/local --eval "$q"
```

and then export it as .csv using mongoexport

```
../mongodb/bin/mongoexport --csv --db local --collection changelog -o changelog.csv --fields "o._id","op","ns","h"
```

and removinf the temporary database to support future changelogs

```
../mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017/local --eval 'db.changelog.remove()'
```